# How do we implement the functions of list (which was in python) as arrays in C language?

Tags: c, arrays, list, programming-languages, python-3.x

I need to implement the "list" data-structure that we use in python. list in python : http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html
I have to implement the functions of list, considering the lists as arrays and need to allocate the memory to it dynamically.
I need to use functions, pointers and structures wherever necessary. (In C language!)

Comment: Do you want us to do it for you? :)

Comment: I don't want you to write the whole program. Just a little demo code would do. I just need to have an idea about memory allocation in arrays dynamically and how to implement them for different functions..

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Comment: Sorry, but if this is your homework and you know nothing about dynamic allocation, then you should do some reading first. Python's lists have many methods, you can't cover all of them in one answer. I'm sure you had some lectures covering this stuff, at least the basics. If you actually try to implement it and get stuck on a specific problem, then it's the right time to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simulate linked list you must study these topics

1.Dynamic Memory allocation using [malloc calloc realloc and free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc)

2.Structures in c

3.Basic pointers in c
For Dynamic Memory allocation you could visit

[Dynamic Memory Allocation in c](http://cprogramminglanguage.net/c-dynamic-memory-allocation.aspx)

A nice tutorial is given here [Linked List in C](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/linked_list.aspx)

**EDIT**

The array implementation of a list is easier as compared to linked list implementaion.In array implementaion also you could use malloc to dynamically allocate memory for your array and realloc to increase/decrease the memory.

for e.g

```
int *base;
int initial_size; //Take Input from user.
base=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * initla_size);
if(!base)  //Ensure if memory is allocated
{
       //Rest of the code 
}
Now to insert eleements you could simply use 
base[i]=element;
```

But before this you must study how arrays and pointers work in C language, and more specifically Dynamic memeory allocation part..

Comment: Thanks a lot for this link. But I need to implement this as arrays not as linked lists.

Answer (score 0):

You need a data structure that contains a pointer to an array containing the data and an integer containing the size of the array. If you don't want to expand the array every time a new item is added, keep track of the number of items in the list also, so you can grow the array by more than is needed.

You can use `malloc` to create the array and data structure, `realloc` to grow the array, and `free` to free the array and data structure.